# WalletConnect stellar_signXDR method returns an XDR object that does not match the usual response data

Tags: manageofferoperation

When successfully creating an offer we get a convenient response object with the offer's data.

However, with [WalletConnect](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/advanced/rpc-reference/stellar-rpc)'s `stellar_signXDR` it sends back an XDR object that when decoded does not contain the expected/needed data to manage the offer.
I suspect this occurs for other operations and transactions also.

How can we get the usual response data that contains `offerResults`, `currentOffer` etc like below?

```
{
  created_at
  envelope_xdr
  fee_account
  fee_charged
  fee_meta_xdr
  hash
  id
  ledger
  max fee
  memo_type
  offerResults
  operation_count
  paging_token
  preconditions
  result_meta_xdr
  result_xdr
  signatures
  source_account
  source_account_s
  successful
  valid_after
  valid_before
  links
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `stellar_signXDR`, what you get is the same transaction you sent to the wallet but signed. This is the one you need to submit to the network later using any horizon available.

Btw I'm the one who told you about the `stellar_signXDR` method on twitter ;D